# Updating a form using cucumber DataTable

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

I am updating a form using DataTable. How can I update a form in each field within the same step and verify the updated form on the next step?

This is the feature file I've created

```
Scenario Outline: Update Entry
And I update entry  
    |   fname   | <fname>   |
    |   lname   | <lname>   |
    |   email   | <email>   |
    |   number  | <number>  |
    |   gender  | <gender>  |

Examples:
|fname  |lname  |email      |number     |gender |
|AAA    |bbb    |aa@aa.com  |987654321  |male   |
```

This is the step definition I have created: (I know this is wrong. I'm stuck on how can this step able to fill up each textbox based on the examples I declare.)

```
@Then("^I update entry$")
public void i_enter_new_entry(DataTable dt) throws Throwable {
      Map<String,String> m =  dt.asMap(String.class,String.class);

      System.out.println("\nFilling form with below data\n");
        for( String k : m.keySet())
        {
            System.out.println("Key -> " + k + " Value -> " + m.get(k));
            enterText(fname_textbox, m.get(k));
            enterText(lname_textbox, m.get(k));
            enterText(email_textbox, m.get(k));
            enterText(number_textbox, m.get(k));
            enterText(gender_textbox, m.get(k));
        }

}
```

So basically my issue is, from the scenario outline, I want to update the entry into each textbox.

Please advice how to do this. Do I need to do getter and setter to store the data?

Comment: Not sure you can use data tables with scenario outline tbh. But have you tried making your problem smaller? I.e. start with filling one field from a regular scenario. If that works, fill multiple fields. If that works, use scenario outline.

Comment: U need to use the `@Transpose` annotation in the step definition as the headers are in the column. What version of cucumber are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one. (you need to import cucumber.api.DataTable;)

```
@And("^I update entry$")
public void updateEntry(DataTable args) {

    List<String> elements = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
    LinkedHashMap<String, String> dataTableValues = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < args.getPickleRows().size(); i++) {
        elements.add(args.getPickleRows().get(i).getCells().get(0).getValue());
        values.add(args.getPickleRows().get(i).getCells().get(1).getValue());
        dataTableValues.put(elements.get(i), values.get(i));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++) {
        WebElement textbox = null;
        switch (elements.get(i)) {
            case "fname":
                textbox = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("your selector here"));
                break;
            case "lname":
                textbox = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("your selector here"));
                break;
            case "email":
                textbox = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("your selector here"));
                break;
            case "number":
                textbox = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("your selector here"));
                break;
            case "gender":
                textbox = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("your selector here"));
                break;
            default:
                fail("'" + elements.get(i) + "' is not part of the common DataTable arguments!");
                break;
        }
        textbox.sendKeys(values.get(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: And you could use the same logic to verify the expected values on the next step (small modification is needed :) )

Comment: Hi. thanks for this.. :)  but small issue, getPickleRows() is undefined for DataTable. do i need to update my maven dependencies?

Comment: import cucumber.api.DataTable;  :)

Comment: Hi Mr Cas, i cant import the getPickleRows(). But im i got getGherkinRows(). Unable to test your code. Thanks

Comment: getPickleRows() is present here: https://static.javadoc.io/io.cucumber/cucumber-core/2.4.0/index.html?cucumber/api/DataTable.html   you need to check the version you are using..